# How to count occurrence of a given number in an Array using ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, find-occurrences

I store the result of my Flask server in `this.state.jsondata` and it's a JSON like this `{label{},text{}}`

```js
export default class Success extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        if (props.location.state) {
            this.state = {
                jsondata: props.location.state.referrer,
                upload: true
                
            } //put jsons data in state object
            toast.success('Upload success')
        } else {
            this.state = {
                upload: false
            }
        }
    }    
...
```

So in order to find occurrence in `label` I converted my JSON to an Array and coded something to find the occurrences but my problem is that I want to find the occurrence of 0, 1 and 2 not only 0. You can already see that I'll need to duplicate my code three times and it's a no-go.

```js
render() {
        const arr = []
        Object.keys(this.state.jsondata.label).forEach(key => arr.push({id: key, value: this.state.jsondata.label[key]}))
        
        var search = 0;
        var count = arr.reduce(function(n, val) {
            return n + (val.value === search);
        }, 0);
...
```

How can I modify my code to be able to get occurrence of a given number ?

Here is the whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/p9qxktgz/3/

[EDIT]

`this.state.jsondata` looks like this :

```
{
   "label":{
      "0":0,
      "1":0,
      "2":0,
      "3":0,
      "4":0
   },
   "text":{
      "0":"- Awww, c'est un bummer. Tu devrais avoir david carr du troisième jour pour le faire. ;ré",
      "1":"Est contrarié qu'il ne puisse pas mettre à jour son facebook en le télémaignant ... et peut-être pleurer en conséquence, l'école aujourd'hui aussi. blabla!",
      "2":"J'ai plongé plusieurs fois pour la balle. A réussi à économiser 50% le reste sort de limites",
      "3":"Tout mon corps a des démangeaisons et comme si c'était en feu",
      "4":"Non, il ne se comporte pas du tout. je suis en colère. pourquoi suis-je ici? Parce que je ne peux pas vous voir partout."
   }
}
```

the `arr` is like this : [image: test]

There isn't a "expected" output, all I want to do is to be able to get as an output the occurrence of each diffrent values in `arr`

Comment: Please post the sample input and the expected output .

Comment: @Shyam I edited my post

Comment: What is the expected output for the screenshot which you have posted ?

Comment: as an output I want the number of occurrence for a given number (here the occurrence of 0 is 5)

Comment: So does it have to be an object like { 0: 5 } ?

Comment: It would be nice so the object could be like { 0:5, 1:0, 2:1} for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const jsonInput = {
   "label":{
      "0":0,
      "1":0,
      "2":0,
      "3":0,
      "4":0
   }
   }

const occurrenceMap = Object.values(jsonInput.label).reduce((finalMap, item) => {
  finalMap[item] = ++finalMap[item] || 1; 
  
  return finalMap;
} , {})

console.log(occurrenceMap)
```

Comment: edited the answer to get the occurrence from the json directly instead of converting it into an array and then using that to find the occurrence it .